# Ruby parsing file with delimiter—how to not include the delimiter

Tags: ruby, parsing

This does not include the delimiter:

```
"hello1there".split("1").each {|section| puts section}
> hello
> there
```

But when I try something similar with a file:

```
fname = Rails.root.join('db', 'text.txt')
File.foreach(fname, "fish") {|section| puts section}

> Hello there
> How are you
> fish
>
> good bye
> good morning
```

It includes the delimiter `"fish"` at the end of each section. How do I split a file into sections, and not include the delimiter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`foreach`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/IO.html#method-c-foreach) method splits but includes the delimiter, that's just how it works. If you want to hard split on the delimiter and eat that value in the process you can do it manually:

```
File.read(fname).split('fish')
```

Comment: Or `File.foreach(fname,"fish") { |section| section.chomp("fish") }`

Comment: @engineersmnky That's technically more memory efficient, but also more code. A good call depending on the situation.

Comment: @tadman `File.read` will load the whole file at once, not practical for large files. `File.foreach` is blazing fast, so I'm trying to find ways to use it

Comment: @Mirror318 Yeah, there's trade-offs with both approaches. If your file is <1GB the `read` method is usually fine, most servers have more than enough memory to handle that. If you're in a more constrained environment then @engineersmnky's approach is better.